# getting applicationWillTerminate and applicationDidEnterBackground working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to build an app and part of it deals with the need to distinguish between an application entering the background and an application quitting when the user presses closes it from the multi task pane. However from all my research online I find out that it is only possible to do one of the following:

a) Set 'application does not run in background' property in info.plist to YES and hence treat "going to background" as terminate

b) As a default the app going to background sends a notification but terminating it from the multi taskbar does not.

Is it possible to get a notification for both and ensure that the app does not terminate when going to background? Help is really appreciated. I am running the new ios 6.

Vivek

Answer (score 2):

Use nsnotification to detect when the application terminates. This will let you know when the user terminates from the multitask bar

```
 UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(applicationWillTerminate:)
                                             name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification
                                           object:app];
```

Which will call this selector in your file:

```
 - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)notification {
     // Do stuff before termination
 }
```

Otherwise it will just go into background mode depending on how your plist is configured

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the user stops the application from the task manager pane, the application is sent a SIGKILL signal so it wont terminate gracefully and no selectors are called as a result.

If you want to ensure that the application does not get terminated(by the OS) the app should register as either needing GPS or Audio background modes (however bear in mind the application needs to really use the capabilities in the proper way, otherwise it will be rejected during the review process).

here is a simple explanation regarding the callbacks of the delegate:

- applicationWillResignActive - whenvever the application is minimized OR a call is received
- applicationDidEnterBackground - whenever the application is minimized by the user
- applicationWillTerminate - whenever the OS decides to terminate the application to save memory (but not when killed by the user)